# Autocomplete text-field version of dynamic select menu?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I would like to combine to logic from the following railscasts:

102 Auto-Complete Association (https://gist.github.com/2347355)
AND
88 Dynamic Select Menus

So as an example, we could say State is selected, and depending on which state is typed a list of cities are populated into the second autocomplete field. Importantly if someone enters a state that doesn't exist it is accepted by the field, and no cities are populated into the city field.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ajax + an XML file that contains State names and related data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. I would appreciate more details on how to do this specifically for this case, if you could please help. Thank you.